# Is my PowerShell script slow because of calculated properties?

Tags: performance, powershell

I'm fairly new to PowerShell but find it useful when I just need some automation instead of having to break out IDE or code editor+compiler. I have a script that will list files, run it through a custom function and then select specific properties for exporting to CSV.

```
ls .\mydir | Convert-ToMyObject | select -Property IdKey, Timestamp `
  | Export-Csv ".\list.csv"
```

- Note that `Timestamp` is a `[datetime]` object.

The script takes about 20-30 minutes to parse through ~45K files.

However, as soon as I change it as follows, it takes a long, long time to process (at this point, it's been about 2 hours and only finished ~25K files).

```
ls .\mydir | Convert-ToMyObject `
  | select -Property IdKey, @{Name="year";Expression={Timestamp.Year}}, `
    @{Name="month";Expression={Timestamp.Month}}, @{Name="day";Expression={Timestamp.Day}}, `
    @{Name="hour";Expression={Timestamp.Hour}}, @{Name="minute";Expression={Timestamp.Minute}}, `
    @{Name="second";Expression={Timestamp.Second}}, @{Name="millisecond";Expression={Timestamp.Millisecond}} `
  | Export-Csv ".\list.csv"
```

I can't figure out what is the cause of this (my google-fu ain't strong enough) and hope someone can help enlighten me. Is it due to the calculated properties? Or the calls to get the datetime components? Or both?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `Convert-ToMyObject` and not in this part of code.

Comment: Can you post Convert-ToMyObject here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for calculated properties is wrong.  You're missing the pipeline object (`$_`) in the expression.  Compare this:

```
gci | select -Property @{Name="year";Expression={LastWriteTime.Year}}
```

To this:

```
gci | select -Property @{Name="year";Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.Year}}
```

The first version runs very slowly (about 100 ms per file) and produces no useful output at all.  The second one is very fast.

Change your code to this:

```
select -Property IdKey, @{Name="year";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Year}}, `
@{Name="month";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Month}}, @{Name="day";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Day}}, `
@{Name="hour";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Hour}}, @{Name="minute";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Minute}}, `
@{Name="second";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Second}}, @{Name="millisecond";Expression={$_.Timestamp.Millisecond}}
```

Comment: Thanks @BaconBits, I just discovered that the hard way. After running a few hours, it produced exactly what you've described; The datetime components were all empty in the output. As soon as I added the pipeline object, all good. A reminder to self - if it runs slow, better make sure it is correct first.